# SVG: how to make a path/get the points for a path

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm attempting to make a two circle Venn Diagram that has utilizes an interactive SVG (clickable/etc), the inspiration is utilized from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29473362/4309550

My question is, how would you be able to get the long and complicated paths that are posted in the SVG element and would it be easy to get these paths without using a tool like illustrator (as I don't have illustrator/photoshop?) I tried playing around with the path d values in the sample given in the posted stackoverflow page but did not have any success in doing so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: something like `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("path")[0].getAttribute("d");`

Comment: Editing the path could get a little tricky as you might have to edit the `viewBox` dimensions those paths were drawn in. There is a an open source vector program called [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) that you could use to create your vectors.

Comment: @maioman That's not what I'm trying to ask. I'm trying to make a new Venn Diagram with two circles instead of three as listed. I do not know how to make the two circles and their intersection as paths (e.g. how to change the values of the d to make the correct circle shapes). Sorry for the confusion and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not work with the circle element instead?

Comment: @RobertLongson, For my code, I want the each section to be interactive (e.g. click the shared section and returns what is in the shared section) and I assumed that this would not be possible with the circles option (there would be only 2 circles targettable instead of the 3 paths that I would want)

Comment: @DavidMa the overlapping bits can be detected as being covered by two or three circles per my answer. Doesn't that give you what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a specific [circle element in SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) with which you can easily make circles;

here's a function for making SVG circles:

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
svg.setAttribute("width", "100%");
svg.setAttribute("height", "100%");


function circle(arr,rad, c) {
    var newElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
    newElement.setAttribute("cx", arr[0]);
    newElement.setAttribute("cy", arr[1]);
    newElement.setAttribute("r", rad);
    newElement.style.fill = c;
    newElement.style.stroke = 'black';
    svg.appendChild(newElement);

}

circle([80, 80], 30, 'rgba(255,0,255,0.3)');
circle([100, 80], 30, 'rgba(255,0,255,0.3)')
circle([90,100], 30, 'rgba(255,0,255,0.3)');
/*you place x,y position as an array in first function argument*/
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```

Actually the example you link to is made with distinct paths so to add animation on hover

### edit:

the easiest workaround, that comes to my mind,for solving your problem is creating 2 circles and an overlapping double-arc to represent intersection:

```css
svg > *:hover {
    fill:#00ff00
}
```

```html
<svg width="325px" height="325px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx='58' cy='100' r='30' stroke='rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.4)' stroke-width='1px' fill='#fff' />
    <circle cx='102' cy='100' r='30' stroke='rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.4)' stroke-width='1px' fill='#fff' />
    <path d="M80 80
           A 30 30, 0, 0, 1, 80 120
            M80 80
           A 30 30, 0, 0, 0, 80 120
           " stroke='rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.4)' stroke-width='1px' fill='#fff' />
</svg>
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/8enezngh/)

Comment: Yeah, the issue would be that I would want the middle sections between the circles to be clickable, which would print the list of the elements that are in the combined circle. But thank you for your time inputting sample code for me.

Comment: @DavidMa designing an arc is not that difficult (check edit); the more difficult part would be developing a function that finds intersecting circles, and create a an arc from that .. ;)

Comment: For current purposes, I'd only need two and three intersecting circles (and not fully develop a intersecting circle function). Thank you. But just being curious, how did you figure out exactly what the path coordinates are? The whole thing seems very nebulous if I need to expand and make a fourth circle.

Comment: @DavidMa you could also use clipping mask to define circle intersections  and it would be much simpler ; with JS you could do it dynamically -[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/a37pasy5/)

Answer (score 2):

You can detect which section has been clicked on even with circles. This answer is expanded from maioman's original with an alert which counts how many overlapping circles exist at the point in question.

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
svg.setAttribute("width", "100%");
svg.setAttribute("height", "100%");

function go(e) {
    var count = 1;
    e.target.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    var t2 = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    if (t2 instanceof SVGCircleElement) {
        ++count;
    }
    t2.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    var t3 = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    if (t3 instanceof SVGCircleElement) {
        ++count;
    }
    e.target.style.pointerEvents = "visiblePainted";
    t2.style.pointerEvents = "visiblePainted";
    alert(count);
}

function circle(arr,rad, c) {
    var newElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
    newElement.setAttribute("cx", arr[0]);
    newElement.setAttribute("cy", arr[1]);
    newElement.setAttribute("r", rad);
    newElement.style.fill = c;
    newElement.style.stroke = 'black';
    newElement.addEventListener("click", go, false);
    svg.appendChild(newElement);

}

circle([80, 80], 30, 'rgba(255,0,255,0.3)');
circle([100, 80], 30, 'rgba(255,0,255,0.3)')
circle([90,100], 30, 'rgba(255,0,255,0.3)');
/*you place x,y position as an array in first function argument*/
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```